# Getting an ADR error in a y86 program, have no idea why. Stack appears to be set up well

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, cpu, y86

I have the following y86-64 program from CMU's Architecture lab that's supposed to sum up the values of a linked list.

```
    # Adam Cooper ac251190

init:
        .pos 0x0
        irmovq Stack, %rsp  # set up stack pointer
        irmovq Stack, %rbp   # set up base pointer
        call Main
        halt

# Sample linked list
.align 8
ele1:
        .quad 0x00a
        .quad ele2
ele2:
        .quad 0x0b0
        .quad ele3
ele3:
        .quad 0xc00
        .quad 0

Main:
        irmovq ele1, %rax
        pushq  %rax        # Pointer to list pushed to stack
        call   Sum
        ret

Sum:
        pushq  %rbp           # Push %rbp onto the stack
        rrmovq %rsp, %rbp
        mrmovq 8(%rbp), %rdx  # Move ele1 into %rdx
        irmovq $0, %rax       # Set up a base to add eles to
        andq   %rdx, %rdx     # Is this the end of the list?
        je     End            # If it is, jump to the end
        irmovq $8, %rcx       # Turn %rcx into a index mover

Loop:
        mrmovq (%rdx), %rbx   # Move ls into %rbx
        addq   %rbx, %rax     # val += ele
        addq   %rcx, %rdx     # Move to next value in the list
        mrmovq (%rdx), %rdx
        andq   %rdx, %rdx     # Are we at the last ele?
        jne    Loop           # If not, go again

End:
        popq %rbp # TEAR! DOWN! THE STACK!
        ret       # Return the original call to Main

        .pos 0x400
Stack:
```

The program halts with status `"ADR"` at line `0x093` which is the line

```
Loop: 
        mrmovq (%rdx), %rbx
```

Now, I was led to believe by the documentation that an `"ADR"` error meant the program was trying to access an address higher that `0xFFF`, but it's not. The stack also appears to have been initialized and set up correctly. I used the same method as several other programs I've written that worked fine. Not really sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Fixed it. Changed `mrmovq 8(%rbp), %rdx` to `mrmovq 16(%rbp), %rdx`. Thanks to anybody who considered helping